# select won't show itself and choosing an option won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

i got a html-dummy (http://www.gisa.de/formular_test/anmeldeformular.html) from another company and now i am trying to create a web-form (http://www.gisa.de/2359.html) based on that dummy.
i am using the same scripts, the basic structure is the same as the dummy, i've compared the sh** out of the code and found nothing. I found one thing with firebug: the site with the non-working select-block won't call the function custom_select from the script.js file - but why???

[image]

i hope someone will find a solution, or something that i've just overlooked

i made 2 jsfiddle out of it:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/WbXsv/1/

http://fiddle.jshell.net/95Q8P/1/

Comment: Not nearly enough information here to help

Comment: You probably have hide of the select in CSS but new styled select is created in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not the same. On your page, you're missing two spans in your div `select`.
Your page:

```
<div class="select">
    <select name="anrede" id="anrede" required="" class="input" style=">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">bitte auswählen</option>
      <option value="Frau">Frau</option>
      <option value="Herr">Herr</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Their page:

```
<div class="select">
    <select name="anrede" id="anrede" required="" class="input" style=">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">bitte auswählen</option>
      <option value="Frau">Frau</option>
      <option value="Herr">Herr</option>
    </select>
    <span class="select-icon"></span>
    <span class="select-box">bitte auswählen</span>
</div>
```

Adding those solved the issue.

Comment: those 2 spans were added by javascript, they are not in the real html-source! ... the problem is that the function wont add those 2 span to the faulty site ... and even when i add thos 2 span - the selected option wont appear!

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
.js select {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

in gisa.css and `custom_select` function is adding custom html in place of hidden select.